# Should we create community ads for Microsoft Connect items we want to promote?

Tags: discussion

If yes, say which Connect item you want and why. Let's discuss this here so we can focus on creating the ads we already agree on.

Comment: Mods: Couldn't add `community-ads` tag to this question.

Comment: Yeah, you don't really get to add that tag.

Comment: @jcolebrand - Yes love, but you can.  :)  'Tis appropriate, is it not?

Comment: 'tis not. they fit a certain format of post.

Comment: http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/457/community-promotion-ads-4q-2011

Comment: @jcolebrand - Oh, only that type of thread may have the tag, eh? OK. Well, do we need a new thread for Q1 2012?

Comment: Sure, if people are gonna make such ads for it

Comment: I think this is a great idea

Comment: Not sure how much attention they actually pay to these suggestions. e.g. still no [`CREATE OR REPLACE`](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/127219/create-or-replace) after 7 years and 335 upvotes.

Comment: @MartinSmith: there as an admission that unless active and nagged and pushed by MVP types, they fall off the radar. Dunno where I saw that.

Answer (score 4):

## [SET STRICT_CHECKS ON](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/260762/add-optional-checks-for-more-robust-development)

Erland Sommarskog's [full explanation of this suggestion is here](http://www.sommarskog.se/strict_checks.html).  The main benefit to implementing this is speedier development and easier troubleshooting for silly but common errors.

From [Erland's Connect suggestion](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/260762/add-optional-checks-for-more-robust-development):

> As programming environment SQL Server has shortcomings that are
>   entirely inappropriate for enterprise development. In a modern
>   programming language, the compile tries to catch as many errors as
>   possible. The earlier errors are found, the cheaper it is to fix them.
>   And nothing is as cheap as a  compiler slapping the error in your
>   face.

`SET STRICT_CHECKS ON` would enforce several compile-time checks that would ferret out easy errors--errors that are currently not caught until run time and are also poorly reported on.